# Can I apply a CSS to one specific Ember.js template / route

Tags: css, ember.js

At the moment, I have a webpage (or more like an embedded part of a webpage) that I need to have different CSS from the rest of the Web application. The reason is because I'm transferring Data from one Ember website to another Ember website and I need the data to look exactly the same on both sites.

Is such a thing possible? I tried using things such as

**app.css**

```
#remove_style {
  all: initial
}
```

But that doesn't reset to browser defaults (meaning if I do `p {color: blue}` then using `initial` will still make all `<p>` elements blue.

I also looked at some libraries such as https://github.com/trentmwillis/ember-css-routes, but it looks old and unmaintained?

I think ideally, I could have a different stylesheet load for a route but I'm not sure if that's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly prevent the styles from leaking *out* of the application by using sass (http://sass-lang.com/), perhaps with an addon like `ember-body-class`. Preventing styles that are not well name-spaced from polluting the inner application sounds like more of a troublesome issue; the simplest fix I can think of is just a stylesheet for the inner application that patches out unwanted stuff.

Comment: Makes sense. I wish there was an easier solution to handle with the leakage. Sass looks helpful for future projects though.